# Update a table from another table with nested trigger in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, triggers

I have a question regarding trigger in sql server. So I got this table :

In Status Table

> InStatusID Time CarID
>
> 1         NULL   10

and another table which has all primary key from other tables (including the one I posted above) :

Car Table

> CarID InStatusID OutStatusID ColorID
>
> 1         1   2                   9

When inserting data for car table, I need to fill them with ID from other tables. However, the GUI from the application didn't need the column for InStatusID to be inserted by the user.
My solution is to make a trigger on Car Table Insert to insert new values for In Status table with the CarID i got from inserted, then when inserting for In Status table there will be another trigger that will update the car table's InStatusID on the same CarID.

For now my trigger look like this :

1. Car Insert Trigger

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_Cars_InsertStatus] ON [dbo].[Cars.Cars]
   AFTER INSERT  
   AS
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   SET NOCOUNT ON 
   SET XACT_ABORT ON

   BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
   DECLARE @ID int

   SELECT @ID=i.CarID from inserted i

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cars.InStatuses] ([Time],[Created],[LastModified],[CarID]) values (NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@ID)
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cars.OutStatuses] ([Time],[Created],[LastModified],[CarID]) values (NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@ID)

   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT
   ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
   ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
   ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
   ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
   ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
   ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

   END CATCH;


   END
   ```
2. In Status/Out Status Insert Trigger

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_OutStatus_InsertCarID] ON [dbo].[Cars.OutStatuses]
   AFTER INSERT  
   AS
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   SET NOCOUNT ON 
   SET XACT_ABORT ON


   BEGIN TRY
   DECLARE @ID int

   SELECT @ID=i.OutStatusID from inserted i

   UPDATE [dbo].[Cars.Cars]
   SET OutStatusID=@ID

   FROM [dbo].[Cars.Cars] CAR 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Cars.OutStatuses] STA
   ON CAR.CarID = STA.CarID
   END
   ```

The code runs but there is a bug : Every time the car table updated, every row on the car table would be udpated too. I thought I have tackled that problem by using JOIN ON but no success. Could anyone help me?

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. So e.g. `SELECT @ID=i.OutStatusID from inserted i` is going to pick a random ID from one of the rows (or be NULL) and all other rows will be ignored. Rather than reading into scalar variables, make `inserted` one of the tables that you `JOIN` to.

Answer (score 0):

simply dont put FK InStatusID on table Car. just put FK CarID on InStatusID

you dont need put both of FK on another table because its 1-1 relationship